# ngfactory not found / Cannot find module

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, universal

Angular 4 App with Universal (ng new myapp)
im trying to exiting A4 app migrate to Angular universal

tsconfig.json

```
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
      "genDir": "./dist/ngfactory",
      "entryModule": "./src/app/app.module#AppModule"
  }
```

after run "npm run start"

```
"scripts": {
    "prestart": "ng build --prod && ngc",
    "start": "ts-node src/server.ts"
  },
```

im getting a error i have no idea about the error thoo.

```
 ERROR in F:/aMoneyworkz/moneyworkz-ng/src/$$_gendir/app/Home/home.component.ngfactory.ts (17,21): Cannot find module './slider/s
lider.component.ngfactory'.

ERROR in F:/aMoneyworkz/moneyworkz-ng/src/$$_gendir/app/Home/home.component.ngfactory.ts (19,22): Cannot find module './three-ac
tion-btn/three-action-btn.component.ngfactory'.

ERROR in F:/aMoneyworkz/moneyworkz-ng/src/$$_gendir/app/Home/home.component.ngfactory.ts (21,22): Cannot find module './feat-par
tners/feat-partners.component.ngfactory'.

ERROR in F:/aMoneyworkz/moneyworkz-ng/src/$$_gendir/app/Home/home.component.ngfactory.ts (17,21): Cannot find module './slider/s
lider.component.ngfactory'.

ERROR in F:/aMoneyworkz/moneyworkz-ng/src/$$_gendir/app/Home/home.component.ngfactory.ts (19,22): Cannot find module './three-ac
tion-btn/three-action-btn.component.ngfactory'.

ERROR in F:/aMoneyworkz/moneyworkz-ng/src/$$_gendir/app/Home/home.component.ngfactory.ts (21,22): Cannot find module './feat-par
tners/feat-partners.component.ngfactory'.

ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir/app/Home/home.component.ngfactory.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './slider/slider.component.ngfactory' in 'F:\aMoneyworkz\moneyworkz-ng\src\$$_gendir\app\
Home'
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/Home/home.component.ngfactory.ts 15:0-58
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.component.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir/app/Home/home.component.ngfactory.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './three-action-btn/three-action-btn.component.ngfactory' in 'F:\aMoneyworkz\moneyworkz-n
g\src\$$_gendir\app\Home'
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/Home/home.component.ngfactory.ts 17:0-79
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.component.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir/app/Home/home.component.ngfactory.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './feat-partners/feat-partners.component.ngfactory' in 'F:\aMoneyworkz\moneyworkz-ng\src\
$$_gendir\app\Home'
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/Home/home.component.ngfactory.ts 19:0-73
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.component.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

pls some one help me with this ....

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312303?