# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory'

Tags: angular, typescript

just yesterday my code was working fine, made no changes to the app module and today when using "ng build --prod" I get this error. I know that it's not related to changes, when I pull older branches I get the same error. I don't know what to do, a recommendation was to update each package, but even after I still get the same error. Not even sure if you guys can help, but here's my app.module:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
import {CompareComponent} from './compare/compare.component';
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {CompareCardComponent} from './compare/compare-card/compare-card.component';
import {LayoutComponent} from './layout/layout.component';
import {CompareValuePipe} from "./compare/compare-card/compare-card.pipe";
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {NewLocationComponent} from './new-location/new-location.component';
import {SignupComponent} from './signup/signup.component';
import {ValidateMe} from "./shared/me.suite/validate.me/validate.me";
import {TagsComponent} from './tags/tags.component';
import {GoogleplaceDirective} from './third-party/angular2-google-map-auto-complete/directives/googleplace.directive';
import { LoaderComponent } from './shared/loader/loader.component';
import { AlertComponent } from './shared/alert/alert.component';
import {Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics, Angulartics2Module} from "angulartics2";
import { OverallPipe } from './compare/overall.pipe';
import {InteractiveComponent} from "./question/interactive/interactive.component";
import { FormComponent } from './question/form/form.component';
import { KpiDescComponent } from './compare/kpi-desc/kpi-desc.component';
import {HashLocationStrategy, Location, LocationStrategy} from "@angular/common";
import {AccountApi} from "./services/account-api.service";
import {SettingsApi} from "./services/settings-api.service";
import {DataApi} from "./services/data-api.service";
import { ZeezorInfoComponent } from './zeezor-info/zeezor-info.component';

const ROUTES = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'compare', component: CompareComponent},
    {path: 'new', component: NewLocationComponent},
    {path: 'tags', component: TagsComponent},
    {path: 'interactive', component: InteractiveComponent},
    {path: 'form', component: FormComponent},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent},
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: '**', component: HomeComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        LayoutComponent,
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        CompareComponent,
        CompareCardComponent,
        CompareValuePipe,
        InteractiveComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        NewLocationComponent,
        SignupComponent,
        ValidateMe,
        TagsComponent,
        GoogleplaceDirective,
        LoaderComponent,
        AlertComponent,
        OverallPipe,
        FormComponent,
        KpiDescComponent,
        ZeezorInfoComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES),
        Angulartics2Module.forRoot([ Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics ])
    ],
    providers: [AccountApi, DataApi, SettingsApi, Location, {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(){
        let style = document.createElement('link');
        style.rel = "stylesheet";
        style.href = SettingsApi.styleEndpoint;
        window.document.head.appendChild(style);
        console.log(navigator.userAgent);
    }
}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "stack-up",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compile": "ng build --environment=mobile --output-path ../mobile/www/",
    "compile:prod": "ng build --environment=mobile --target=production --output-path ../mobile/www/",
    "docker": "ng build --environment=docker",
    "local": "ng serve --environment=local",
    "dev": "ng build --environment=dev",
    "prod": "ng build --environment=prod --target=production --output-path /var/www/html/"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.2",
    "angular2-social-login": "^2.1.0",
    "angulartics2": "^2.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.31",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem yesterday (same error message) and I fixed it based on this angular-cli issue:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7125

The fix was to pin `enhanced-resolve` to version `3.3.0` in my package.json, delete node_modules, run `npm install`, then build again. This seems to have fixed the problem for some of the people in the issue thread.

The newer version of enhanced-resolve seems to be causing some problem.

If it still breaks make sure you have the correct enhanced-resolve version by running `npm ls enhanced-resolve`.

Comment: Cha-Ching! Thanks man, I saw that thread, tried it, but didn't get the specific version or uninstall the node_modules. Cheers!

Comment: Is 'pin' the term used instead of 'add' in a package?

Comment: 'pin' means to set a specific version. For package.json that means removing any tilde (~) or caret (^) characters from the version string. In this case "enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0" is added to the package.json so that specific version is used.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else coming accross this, there was a descrepency with older versions of `angular-cli` and `angular`. [Source](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7125).

To resolve this, upgrade `angular-cli` to `@latest`.

> ```
> npm uninstall -g angular-cli
> npm cache clean
> npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
> ```
>
> Depending on your system, you may need to prefix the above commands
>   with sudo.
>
> Also, most likely you want to also update your local project version,
>   because inside your project directory it will be selected with higher
>   priority than the global one:
>
> ```
> rm -rf node_modules
> npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
> npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
> npm install
> ```
>
> [How to upgrade Angular CLI to the latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue today. I tried running the command:

ng build --env=prod instead of ng build --prod and it seems to have solved it without adding enhanced-resolve in the package.json.

Comment: this was the ticket for me -- having to use node v6 and an old set of deps to try and rebuild the current release of something mean I had to:

1. clear node_modules and let it re-download everything
2. use the `--env=prod` argument to ng build

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use @latest angular-cli, update @angular-cli at least to v1.2.6. It's solved issue for now and you don't need to install enhanced-resolve and so on. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7113

Answer (score 0):

[image]As mentioned in the previous answer, the enahnced-resolve version 3.4.1 was causing the issue. Using version 3.3.0 fixes the issue. We can pin the dpendencies versions using nopm-srinkwrap.json